# Format for including html within my foreach DataRow

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using DataSet to display selected fields from the database.

```
foreach (DataRow row in dsNews.Tables["News"].Rows)
{
    newsTitle.Text += "<dd>";
    newsTitle.Text += "<p><a href=""news-edit?id=" + row["newsID"] + """>" + row["newsTitle"] + "</a></p>";
    newsTitle.Text += "</dd>";
}
```

Eventually it will be used to edit a news post.

The following line is giving me trouble:

```
newsTitle.Text += "<p><a href=""news-edit?id=" + row["newsID"] + """>" + row["newsTitle"] + "</a></p>";
```

Is the above format not correct? It is clear what I am wanting to do - but the compiler is asking for a `;`

I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't handled your quotes properly. If you want double quoted attributes, you need to escape the embedded doublequotes with a backslash.

```
newsTitle.Text += "<p><a href=\"news-edit?id=" + row["newsID"] + "\">" + row["newsTitle"] + "</a></p>";
```

Or it's easier to switch to single quotes for your attributes. It thus becomes:

```
newsTitle.Text += "<p><a href='news-edit?id=" + row["newsID"] + "'>" + row["newsTitle"] + "</a></p>";
```

However, this is a terrible way of injecting repeated content into your webpage. Instead, define a class to represent your data:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your code, retrieve the collection of articles and bind them to a repeater.

Web Form

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="ArticleRepeater" ItemType="MyNamespace.Article">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p>
            <a href="news-edit?id=<%#: Item.Id %>"><%#: Item.Title %></a>
        </p>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind

```
IEnumerable<Article> articles = DataLayer.GetArticles();
ArticleRepeater.DataSource = articles;
ArticleRepeater.DataBind();
```

Obviously you'll need to implement a data layer of some sort, likely using an ORM such as Entity Framework or a Micro ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: Many thanks @mason. I don't understand how you do not HAVE to make a Class to read your data? A repeater that is binded will do the same job, then you can use Eval etc... But, is what you are presenting using get; set; just a better way of doing it? Thanks...

Comment: @davvv A strongly typed class that represents your data (a model) is far easier to work with in C# than a DataTable. A DataTable bound to a repeater will rely on "magic strings" to get the column, you don't get Intellisense and it can't tell you at compile time if a column name is out of sync on your Eval call. It would only fail at runtime. Models also use far less memory than a DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?  For C# and Javascript, you're not escaping your quotes.

So this line:

```
newsTitle.Text += "<p><a href=""news-edit?id=" + row["newsID"] + """>" + row["newsTitle"] + "</a></p>"
```

reads

```
newsTitle.Text += "<p><a href="
"news-edit?id=" + row["newsID"] + ""
">" + row["newsTitle"] + "</a></p>"
```

You end up with one assignment and two strings that don't do much of anything (except syntax error)

in javascript, you can fix this by using half-quotes:

```
newsTitle.Text += '<p><a href=""news-edit?id=' + row["newsID"] + '"">' + row["newsTitle"] + '</a></p>'
```

... and that shows another concern; your href is being opened and closed without content in it.

in C#, you can use:

```
newsTitle.Text += "<p><a href=\"\"news-edit?id=" + row["newsID"] + "\"\">" + row["newsTitle"] + "</a></p>"
```

... which still doesn't look like it will give what you're really looking for.